# Any Google search results page gives me a blank screen in Google Chrome. Bing and Yahoo both work

Tags: google-search, blank-screen

Any Google search results page gives me a blank screen. The search results are there; I can click on them blindly. I cannot see the page at all.

I've tried multiple browsers, so the problem is not there.
I've also tried clearing my cookies and history.
Other search engines are perfectly normal and fine. Bing and Yahoo both work.
I've also reset my firewall settings to default.

Comment: Can you see other pages? Check if you did set up some special format (like white font on white ground or some such nonsense) for Google. Worst case, blow away (or move out of the way) whatever files store your browser configuration and try again.

Answer (score 0):

The solution(s) that I found from articles [How to Fix Chrome Blank page(s) problem](https://www.wintips.org/fix-google-chrome-blank-page-problem/), [Fix: Google Chrome Blank or White Pages](https://appuals.com/google-chrome-blank-or-white-pages/) (Steps 1-5 are from Article 1):

- 1. "Preventing Chrome from running in *Windows XP compatibility mode"*
- End all Chrome Tasks in the Task Manager;Open Task Manager by Finding it on your computer, right click on the Chrome Tasks, and select "*End Task*" or "*End Process*"
- Deselect "*Run this program in compatibility mode for *"; find Chrome on your computer, either on your Desktop, Start Menu, taskbar, etc..; Right click on Chrome; go to compatibility; and deselect the checkbox before "*Run this program in compatibility mode for*"
- If this solves the problem then scan your computer with an antivirus software, and go to step 4.

---

- 2. Disable Chrome's "Sandbox" **(Note: this is considered a security feature and disabling it may not be worth it, if you're worried about viruses and malware on your computer)**:
- Find Chrome on your computer
- Right click on Chrome
- Go to properties
- In the Shortcut tab, go to the "*Target"* field, and add to current input "*-no-sandbox*"
- Then launch Chrome to see whether or not the problem is solved

---

- 3. Empty the Chrome "Local Storage" folder:
- Enable the ability to view hidden files on your computer; then go into the "*Google Chrome Local Storage folder*"; Go to the Control panel, and open Folder Options; Select View; Under "*Hidden files and folders*" select "*Show hidden files, folders, and drives*"; and then Click "*OK*"
- End all the tasks of Chrome in the Task Manager; open the Task Manager, and right click on the running tasks of Chrome, and select "*End Task*"
- Enter the following folder path in the file explorer, in the input  filed at the very top: C:\Users<You Username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Storage\
- Then Launch Chrome to see if the problem is solved

---

- 4. Use an antivirus program to scan your computer, and remove any malicious files
- Here's a [Malware scan and removal guide](https://www.wintips.org/quick-malware-check-removal-guide/):
- Run Chrome to see if the problem is solved

---

- 5. Get a new copy of Chrome, "Start Fresh" **(Note: If you don't back up all your data, your bookmarks settings, etc.., it will be lost**:
- Here are articles ([1](https://www.wintips.org/how-to-import-and-export-your-bookmarks-in-google-chrome/), [2](https://www.wikihow.com/Backup-and-Restore-Google-Chrome%27s-Entire-Settings)) on how to save all your data before you "Start Fresh"
- Uninstall the Chrome that is currently on you computer; go to The Start Menu, right click, and uninstall (Windows 10, this is my assumption on what would work to uninstall and not from articles linked); or go to the Control panel, "*Add or Remove programs*" (For Windows XP, "*Programs and Features*" (For Windows 7, 8 and Vista)
- Find Chrome in the program list and uninstall
- Delete Chrome Folders from your computer;
- Enable the ability to view hidden files
  - Go to the Start Menu
  - Go to the Control panel
  - Open Folder Options
  - Select View
  - Under "*Hidden files and folders*" select "*Show hidden files, folders, and drives*"
  - and then Click "*OK*
  - Follow the paths based on your OS; Windows 7, 8 & 7:

  - C:\Users<YourUserName>\AppData\Local\Google\
  - C:\Users<YourUserName>\AppData\Local\Google
    - Windows XP:
  - C:\Documents and Settings<YourUserName>\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\
  - C:\Program Files\Google
    - Delete the folder
    - Then Install a new version of Chrome (using another browser) (Article says for all user accounts); How to Fix Chrome Blank page(s) problem][1](https://www.wintips.org/fix-google-chrome-blank-page-problem/) says to download and run the [Offline installer](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/126299) but, I don't know what the purpose of that would be, and would probably use the link provided [here](https://www.google.com/chrome/).

---

- 8. Remove all your Chrome extensions, and if this works one of the extensions could be malicious.

---

- There are more solutions listed in [Fix: Google Chrome Blank or White Pages](https://appuals.com/google-chrome-blank-or-white-pages/).